# R Remove character followed by specific character in Street Address

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to remove everything after certain character but with few exceptions as follows:

In 1st string i want to remove everything after 'st' (my interpretation here is St represents street)  and in 2nd string 'St' represents saint so would like to retain the address as it is.

In 3rd string i want to remove everything after 'Dr' (my interpretation here is Dr represents drive) and in 4th string 'Dr' represents doctor so would like to retain the address as it is.

Below is an sample input

```
str <- c("852 union St End",
         "852 St johns street",
         "30 Sandpiper Dr 35",
         "30 Dr Botero drive")
```

My expected output is

```
c("852 union St",
  "852 St johns street",
  "30 Sandpiper Dr",
  "30 Dr Botero drive")
```

Below is the sample code am using, however it is removing everything after St / Dr

```
Scrubdata <- mgsub(str, 
                     c(" drive.*", " dr .*", 
                       " street.*", " st .*"), 
                     c(" drive", " dr",
                       " street", " st"), ignore.case = T)
```

Has anyone got an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the rule to remove "St" Or "Dr" ?

Comment: Its generally based on discretion of the user, if 'st' or 'dr' is positioned at end of the string it can be treated as street or drive. But if it is in the middle of the string as shown in 2nd and 4th string it can be treated as 'saint' or 'doctor'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way which removes a word after `'St'` or `'Dr'` if there is only one word following it :

```
sub('(?<=(St|Dr)) \\w+$', '', str, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "852 union St"  "852 St johns street" "30 Sandpiper Dr" "30 Dr Botero drive"
```

Using `str_remove` :

```
stringr::str_remove(str, '(?<=(St|Dr)) \\w+$')
```

Comment: This sounds a better answer given the uncertainty about position of 'St' or 'Dr', thank you so much.

Comment: In the above mgsub function if i want to replace Drive/drive with d same case of original string. do u have any other suggestion. Here Although i was matching words using ignore.case =T, while replacing am replacing the small case which is not same for all strings.

Comment: If you want to keep the same case it is better to extract the string from the original string instead of replacing it.